# Redirect after AuthGuard callback in Angular

Tags: angular, auth-guard

I have two routes that require Angular `canActivate: [AuthGuard]`

```
const routes: Routes =  [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: 'projects', 
    children: [
      { path: '', component: ProjectsComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'sjcl', component: HashgenComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]  },
    ]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

As you can see if a user is not logged in he is redirected to `/login` route which by my `AuthGuard`

```
if (this.auth.isLoggedIn) { return true; }

return this.auth.currentUserObservable.pipe(
  take(1),
  map(user => {
    console.log('user: ', user);
    return !!user
  }),
  tap(loggedIn => {
    console.log("loggedIn: ", loggedIn);
    if (!loggedIn) {
      console.log("access denied");
      //this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      this.router.navigate(['login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    }
  })
);
```

And my `login`  component is as follows,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { FirebaseUISignInSuccessWithAuthResult, FirebaseUISignInFailure } from 'firebaseui-angular';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  returnUrl: string;

  constructor(
    public auth: AuthService, 
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
      this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
      console.log("yes i am here");
      console.log(this.returnUrl);
     }

  ngOnInit() {}
  ngAfterViewInit(){

  }
  successCallback(signInSuccessData: FirebaseUISignInSuccessWithAuthResult) {
    console.log("Logged in!"+this.returnUrl);
    this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
  }

  errorCallback(errorData: FirebaseUISignInFailure) {
    console.log("Login failure!");
  }
}
```

**`PROBLEM`**

Now, everything is working fine and well except for one thing. Assume

- I start from `/home` and click on `/projects` and login, i am being redirected to `/projects` after login. (No problem here)
- I start from `/home` and click on `/projects/sjcl` and login, i am being redirected to `/projects/sjcl` after login. (No problem here)
- I start from `/home` and click on `/projects` and then click on `/projects/sjcl` and login, i am being redirected to `/projects` after login, whereas i should've been redirected to `/projects/sjcl` (Problem here)

The thing is,

```
  this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
  console.log("yes i am here");
  console.log(this.returnUrl);
```

is not being called if LoginComponent is already loaded and being called again from another `Authguard`. I tried using different lifecycles and even placed it on constructor still no help.

How should above snippet be called everytime LoginComponent is loaded?

Comment: Dont use snapshot but rather listen to route changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use route `snapshot` but rather listen to route change. `Router` have event for that that you can subscribe to. Update your "return" URL accordingly.

Comment: Worked perfectly! For others, I changed, `this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';` to `this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
      retUrl => {
        this.returnUrl = retUrl.returnUrl;
      }
    );`